# Having problems with subtracting a value from a variable in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before you get mad at me, I am new to python. I am trying to make a text-based game. The health system that I had was not working. I have tried to fix it but I don't think I know enough to fix it.
The problem that I have is when I want to lower the health. When I lower it doesn't lower by the value I give instead it lowered

This is the part code working because I did not try to subtract any value.
The code makes an object and then the code will add to the Total_health variable to make Total health 100.

```
Total_health = 0

class Rover:
  def __init__(self, broken_camera, dirty_solar_panels, system_failure, broken_solar_panels, broken_wheels, signal_interference, battery, bearing_failure, arm, xray, motor_failure):
    self.broken_camera = broken_camera
    self.dirty_solar_panels = dirty_solar_panels
    self.system_failure = system_failure
    self.broken_solar_panels = broken_solar_panels
    self.broken_wheels = broken_wheels
    self.signal_interference = signal_interference
    self.battery = battery
    self.arm = arm
    self.xray = xray
    self.motor_failure = motor_failure

Rover = Rover(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 100, False, False, False)
Rover.battery = 100
def lines():
  print("_____________________________________________")


def health():
  global Total_health
  if Rover.broken_camera == True:
    print("Broken Camera") 
  if Rover.dirty_solar_panels == True:
    print("Dirty Solar Panels")
  if Rover.broken_solar_panels == True:
    print("Broken Solar Panels")
  if Rover.broken_wheels == True:
    print("Broken Wheels")    
  if Rover.battery < 21:
    print("Low Battery 20%")
  if Rover.arm == True:
    print("Arm Damage")
  if Rover.xray == True:
    print("Broken XRAY")
  if Rover.motor_failure == True:
    print("Moror Faliure") 
  print("Total Health:", Total_health)
  lines()


if Rover.broken_camera == True:
  Total_health -= 10
if Rover.broken_camera == False:
  Total_health += 10

if Rover.dirty_solar_panels == True:
  Total_health -= 5

if Rover.dirty_solar_panels == False:
  Total_health += 5

if Rover.broken_solar_panels == True:
  Total_health -= 20  
if Rover.broken_solar_panels == False:
  Total_health += 20  

if Rover.broken_wheels == True:
  Total_health -= 10 
if Rover.broken_wheels == False:
  Total_health += 10    

if Rover.battery < 21: 
  Total_health -= 5 
if Rover.battery > 20:
  Total_health += 5 

if Rover.arm == True:
  Total_health -= 20
if Rover.arm == False:
  Total_health += 20

if Rover.xray == True:
  Total_health -= 10
if Rover.xray == False:
  Total_health += 10

if Rover.motor_failure == True:
  Total_health -= 20
if Rover.motor_failure == False:
  Total_health += 20
  
health()
```

This is the code not working because I tried to subtract a value.

```
Total_health = 0

class Rover:
  def __init__(self, broken_camera, dirty_solar_panels, system_failure, broken_solar_panels, broken_wheels, signal_interference, battery, bearing_failure, arm, xray, motor_failure):
    self.broken_camera = broken_camera
    self.dirty_solar_panels = dirty_solar_panels
    self.system_failure = system_failure
    self.broken_solar_panels = broken_solar_panels
    self.broken_wheels = broken_wheels
    self.signal_interference = signal_interference
    self.battery = battery
    self.arm = arm
    self.xray = xray
    self.motor_failure = motor_failure



Rover = Rover(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 100, False, False, False)
Rover.battery = 100

def lines():
  print("_____________________________________________")

# here this code wont work
Rover.broken_camera = True
# it subtracts 20 insted of 10


def health():
  global Total_health
  if Rover.broken_camera == True:
    print("Broken Camera") 
  if Rover.dirty_solar_panels == True:
    print("Dirty Solar Panels")
  if Rover.broken_solar_panels == True:
    print("Broken Solar Panels")
  if Rover.broken_wheels == True:
    print("Broken Wheels")    
  if Rover.battery < 21:
    print("Low Battery 20%")
  if Rover.arm == True:
    print("Arm Damage")
  if Rover.xray == True:
    print("Broken XRAY")
  if Rover.motor_failure == True:
    print("Moror Faliure") 
  print("Total Health:", Total_health)
  lines()


if Rover.broken_camera == True:
  Total_health -= 10
if Rover.broken_camera == False:
  Total_health += 10

if Rover.dirty_solar_panels == True:
  Total_health -= 5

if Rover.dirty_solar_panels == False:
  Total_health += 5

if Rover.broken_solar_panels == True:
  Total_health -= 20  
if Rover.broken_solar_panels == False:
  Total_health += 20  

if Rover.broken_wheels == True:
  Total_health -= 10 
if Rover.broken_wheels == False:
  Total_health += 10    

if Rover.battery < 21: 
  Total_health -= 5 
if Rover.battery > 20:
  Total_health += 5 

if Rover.arm == True:
  Total_health -= 20
if Rover.arm == False:
  Total_health += 20

if Rover.xray == True:
  Total_health -= 10
if Rover.xray == False:
  Total_health += 10

if Rover.motor_failure == True:
  Total_health -= 20
if Rover.motor_failure == False:
  Total_health += 20
  
health()
```

I know the code is messy but is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Why is `total_health` a global variable, and not an instance attribute of `Rover`?

Answer (score 0):

You have created the rover object with the same name as the class

```
Rover = Rover(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 100, False, False, False)
```

This is a big error, as you will not be able to create any new objects, replace the line with this

```
Rover = Rover(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 100, False, False, False)
```

Then change the reference in all the lines below
for example

```
rover.battery = 100
```

```
rover.battery = 100
```

Now, since you initialized your rover with all aspects as False, according to your code, the value will not be reduced but increased.

```
if Rover.broken_camera == True:
  Total_health -= 10
if Rover.broken_camera == False:
  Total_health += 10
```

To test if you health reduces, you have change the rover battery to 0

```
rover.battery = 0
```